# Magento - Configurable product switch to simple product by color attribute

Tags: magento, colors, swap, configurable

Can anybady help me with something like this one has here : http://www.lahalleauxchaussures.com/chaussures-de-sport-converse-60884.html   ?

When you select the color for a configurable product to bring you the simple product for that color.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Because this is associated product with main config ! its not product option, this is why each color is different entity.

If you want one product create custom options or assign different values for product attribute, and don't make Main configurable product and associate simple products with it.

Comment: If I do like that the product will have same images. How it is right now it's perfect, I'ave found a thing on google ad I've implement it.... when I'm selecting the color it birngs me the simple product images... it's ok like that.. but I want to bring me the full page of the product... This one I have applied to my website. http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-reload-color-images-for-configurable-product?page=1

Comment: you can do small modification in the javascript to change images based on attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension for your need [See This URL](http://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html)

Comment: This is not good because it only changes the media gallery with javascript, it not taking you to the simple prpoduct page taht you have selected !